# Create a string animation like typewriter

Tags: objective-c, animation, nsstring, ios7

I would make a NSString animation typing character by character like a typewriter. The string will be placed on a UILabel. Is possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

woz's method works good, but I can't use it for solve my problem. I'll try to explain my situation. In my app on the first view I would display the actual position, so I added these methods:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    //NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            [address sizeToFit];

            address.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@\n%@ %@\n%@",
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.thoroughfare],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.subThoroughfare],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.postalCode],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.locality],
                            [self sanitizedDescription:placemark.country]];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}

- (NSString *)sanitizedDescription:(NSString *)obj
{
    if (obj == nil)
    {
        obj = @"...";
        return obj;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Now I would use the typewriter animation when `if (obj == nil)` on `- (NSString *)sanitizedDescription:(NSString *)obj` is called. How can I do?

Sorry but I'm at beginning with Obj-C :(

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some code to get you started. I am using NSTimer to add a character to the UILabel at regular intervals.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSTimer *typingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2
        target:self
        selector:@selector(typeALetter:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];

    NSString *stringToType = @"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    NSUInteger index = 0;
}

- (void)typeALetter:(id)sender {

    theLabel.text = [theLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [stringToType substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)]];

    if (index < stringToType.length) {
        index++;
    }
    else {
        [typingTimer invalidate];
    }    

}
```